# AccessからSQL Serverに移行する際のクライアントPCの設定について

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

MS-AccessからSQL Serverへの移行を検討しています。AccessのテーブルをSQL Serverに移しデータ保存用のファイルとし、Accessで作成したフォームやレポートはそのまま入力用として使用、リンクテーブルで接続しようと思っています。

サーバー側にSQL Serverをインストールしテーブルを移行した後、クライアントPCにもSQL ServerをインストールしクライアントPCからサーバー側のSQL Serverに移行したテーブルに接続できることは確認できました。

そこで質問なのですが、クライアントPCにはすべてSQL Serverをインストールした方がいいでしょうか？AccessはすべてのクライアントPCにインストールされています。すべてのクライアントPCにSQL Serverをインストールするのはかなり作業時間がかかり、その他の業務の作業時間を圧迫してしまいます。また、インストールする時間そのPCを占領してしまうことになり、そのPCで行う作業も停止することになります。ですので、できるだけインストールするシステムを少なくしてインストール作業の時間を短縮したいと思っています。最小限クライアントPCにインストールすべきシステムとインストールする方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: インストールの作業時間以前の問題としてSQL Serverのライセンスはどうなっているのでしょうか？

Comment: Expressでやってみようと思っています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Server データベースのインポートまたは SQL Server データベースへのリンク](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/sql-server-%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%E3%81%AF-sql-server-%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%83%99%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF-a5a3b4eb-57b9-45a0-b732-77bc6089b84e)で説明されていますが、AccessはSQL Serverに接続するための機能を持っており、同マシン上にSQL Serverをインストールする必要はありません。
必要であれば、[Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/connect/odbc/windows/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server-on-windows?view=sql-server-ver15)のより新しいバージョンをインストールしてもよいでしょう。

Comment: すみません、勘違いしてました。ご回答ありがとうございました。